# How to run a non java program(C++/Matlab preferred) using Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a requirement stating that  C++ and Matlab algorithm execution should be triggered from Hadoop mapreduce programming.

Will this map the executing algorithm to be distributed.

As we have to no plan to rewrite the algorithm using entire mapreduce program

Answer (score 1):

In R2014b, MATLAB allows mapreduce from within MATLAB and integration with Hadoop.

I cannot be certain about your specific use case but you may want to check:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mapreduce.html

http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-mapreduce-hadoop.html